# Extension struct is not member on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct, extension-methods

Created a simple extension to allow me to give an Identifier to a UITableViewCell, so I can name it, pretty much as Apple does with Notification.Name:

```
// UITableViewCellExtension.swift

extension UITableViewCell {
    public struct Identifier: RawRepresentable {
        public typealias RawValue = String

        public var rawValue: RawValue {
            return self._rawValue
        }

        private var _rawValue: RawValue

        public init(rawValue: RawValue) {
            self._rawValue = rawValue
        }

        public init(_ rawValue: RawValue) {
            self._rawValue = rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

After this the idea was to add this piece of code on an UIViewController so I can get my cell identifiers organized:

```
// SomeViewController.swift

extension UITableViewCell.Identifier {
    static let wololo = UITableViewCell.Identifier("wololo")   
}
```

But I got the following error:

> 'Identifier' is not a member of type 'UITableViewCell'

Now is where things get a little crazier: 
- If I move the same extension on the UITableViewCellExtension.swift, it does compile and everything is alright.
- If I just add the *static let wololo = UITableViewCell.Identifier("wololo")* on the SomeViewController's class body, it works.

Already checked the Target Membership of the extension file and viewController.

---

A little more explanation about the *why?*

```
// UITableViewExtension.swift
extension UITableView {

    ...
    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    open func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: UITableViewCell.Identifier, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier.rawValue, for: indexPath)
    }

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: UITableViewCell.Identifier) {
        register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier.rawValue)
    }

    ...
}
```

That supposed to be the syntax:

```
class PlacesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: .wololo)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: .wololo)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more about syntax, because I've modified how the cells are registered and dequeued, just so I can organize its identifiers without use enums and digit raw value every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this is probably a Xcode bug. If you create a swift file template the 'Identifier' struct is not recognized outside of the file. But if you create a Cocoa Touch template file the 'Identifier' struct is recognized with no problems. 
[templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO9rw.png)

And if you create a swift template file, you can go to build phases -> compile sources -> remove the file and add it again.
Hope it can help you.

[compile sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ0eA.png)

Comment: It really worked, I'll report it as a bug on Developer Apple, thanks for the help.

Comment: I had to put the files in the correct order in the Project Navigator.
Explanation: if A is declared in its file named A and an extension of A called E (A.E) is declared in file B, then in the Project Navigator the A file should appear before file B.

Comment: Perfect solution and explanation. What was weird is that I was able to build and run the application. The only issue is the wrong error from Xcode. Remove / Add the file did work.